# How can I stop the browser from closing automatically?

Tags: vba, selenium

I am using Selenium to log in to some website via EDGE.

The browser window is closing.

How can I stop the window from closing?

```vb
Sub Login_EdgeChrome2()
Dim wd As WebDriver
Set wd = New ChromeDriver

Const URL = "https://mms.fsicloud.me/Evolution/!System/Security/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fEvolution"

With wd
    .Start "Edge"
    .Get URL
    .FindElementById("ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_loginControl_UserName").SendKeys "username"
    .FindElementById("ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_loginControl_Password").SendKeys "password"
    
    .FindElementById("ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_loginControl_LoginButton").Click  '- this will log in with the correct credentials.
    
End With
wd.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:01:30"))
 
End Sub
```

Used to do this in IE. However some features don't work well now in IE.

I tried Selenium to log in via EDGE. However, it logs automatically. So I put the time delay, but after the time lapsed, it will close again.

Answer (score 0):

I confess I don't know much about VB - but from the looks of it, you have a subroutine that creates a localized instance of WebDriver. So when  `Login_EdgeChrome2` ends, the local instance disappears. In my world (in the languages I am familiar with), I'd have to return `wd` as a result of that subroutine to make it "survive".